# There was this cartoon show that I used to watch as a kid. I don't really remember but the main characters were 2 guys and a girl?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this cartoon show that I used to watch as a kid. I don't really remember but the main characters were 2 guys and a girl? If I'm not wrong the girl had like 2 buns and red hair ? The antagonist was a little guy which had his head in something like an aquarium filled with water and he had a really big bodyguard. The bodyguard had a lot of force but was really dumb. I think it was a monkey or something like that. Does anybody know the title? I tried to find it but I can't.

Comment: When were you a kid?

Comment: I'm 15 this year so I think it was somewhere between 2008/2009- 2015

Comment: Maybe check out https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MobileFishbowl for the villain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's [Chop Socky Chooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chop_Socky_Chooks).

The characters seem to somewhat fit.  The girl main character has black hair, but it's in two buns.  It also was out in 2008, so that fits your estimated timeline perfectly.

The main villian (from the Wikipedia page):

> **Dr. Wasabi** (voiced by Paul Kaye) – Dr. Wasabi is the ruler of Wasabi World and is the main antagonist of the show. **He is a little piranha that has an astronaut-like attire with water filled inside** (so as to allow him to breathe) He has control of every place in Wasabi World, yet he has no idea of who the Chop Socky Chooks are. He is armed with his top henchman Bubba and his Ninja Chimps. His name is retained from his green wasabi-like skin color.

(emphasis mine)  The sidekick also seems to match:

> **Bubba** (voiced by Rupert Degas) – **Bubba is a large ape and wears a suit along with a top hat. Although not big intelligently and initially illiterate, he's big in the heart.** He has the dumb and strong personality like many cartoon characters. He has proved himself very useful, besides his impressive strength. His favorite comic book hero is Captain Cockroach and enjoys reading comic books after learning to read.

(emphasis mine) I found this by taking Buzz's advice and using the TV Tropes [mobile fishbowl](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MobileFishbowl) page, and found it under Western Animation.  The TV Tropes page for [Chop Socky Chooks](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ChopSockyChooks) had basically all the information from the question.

Comment: This is it, thank you very much, I've been trying to find it for hours